# Appium. Usage of Xpath axes in locator. Find sibling/parent/child/etc elements in context of curtrent element

Tags: xpath, appium-android

Is it possible to find sibling/parent/child/etc mobile elements in context of existing mobile element.
For example I have basic element:
MobileElement mobileElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//any/xpath/locator"));

Then I need to find following sibling element.
In Selenium I could use similar code:
MobileElement nextMobileElement = mobileElement.findElement("following-sibling::nextelement['any conditions']");
But in appium I getting NoSuchElementException.

What is the proper syntax for usage of xpath axes in Appium to locate elements in defined above way?

Answer (score 1):

In general if you want to find element under a parent element using xpath, add a **.** to the xpath to say that the child element xpath to be searched under the given parent element. So in your case you can try something like :

```
mobileElement.findElement(By.xpath(".(xpath of the child element)")
```

For example mobileElement.findElement(By.xpath("**.**//div[@class='xyz']")

Comment: I know about this feature, and I tried to use a . with single either double / in my xpath expression, but in all cases I got "NoSuchElementException".

Comment: Then can you post your dom xml and the xpath you are trying to use, so that it LL give us a better idea on your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Solution found in next way:
When appium is unable to select element by its name, i.e. there an element <android.widget.ViewAnimator ....>, then you can view it's "class" attribute, and it will contain an identical text: class="android.widget.ViewAnimator". So you can build your Xpath complicated locators based on this attribute. In case of Xpath axes it will look like this: //some/xpath/preceding-sibling::*[@class='android.widget.ViewAnimator'].

Comment: niceeeee. this is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Appium supports XPath as WebDriver does. Make sure your XPath is correct, you can test it in [appium-desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop). `Following-sibling` was working for me without any issues.
When Appium is not able to process XPath expression, you should get the related exception.